# (Synology) How to install apache development package using "ipkg"

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, synology

I'm running Apache on a Synology (with MySQL, PHP). It has been working fine for 2 years and now I want to add flask files to the server.

```
ipkg update
ipkg install python3
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
python3 -m pip install flask
python3 -m pip install pymysql
python3 -m pip install mod_wsgi
```

Those are commands I executed and I got an error when installing mod_wsgi.

Error:

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py                                                                                                  egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Downloading mod_wsgi-4.5.17.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.9 MB 8.3 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys                                                                                                 .argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cwc7qweq/mod-wsgi_71a66a132bc24dcd848d791aee926                                                                                                 2de/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-cwc7qweq/mod-wsgi_71a66a132bc2                                                                                                 4dcd848d791aee9262de/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(_                                                                                                 _file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools impor                                                                                                 t setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.c                                                                                                 lose();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/p                                                                                                 ip-pip-egg-info-4rdjf86x
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-cwc7qweq/mod-wsgi_71a66a132bc24dcd848d791aee9262d                                                                                                 e/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-cwc7qweq/mod-wsgi_71a66a132bc24dcd848d791aee9262de/                                                                                                 setup.py", line 164, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not execu                                                                                                 table. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this pack                                                                                                 age and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

I guess there's no Apache httpd server package and it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` or `sudo yum install httpd`. But those are for Ubuntu and CentOS, not for Synology (ipkg package manager).

Is there any way to install the Apache development package using ipkg?
I would really appreciate any help/response.